# Checkbutton in perl Tk is selecting all options

Tags: perl, perltk

I'm creating a list of checkbuttons in perl tk using a loop.

```
    $i=1;
    $n=5;
    @x=1;
    while($i <= $n){
    $mw->Checkbutton(->text=>$i,-variable=>\$ckval,->command=>sub{
                 if($ckval){print $i}
    })->pack;
    $i=$i+@x;
    }
```

The correct value of i is printed on the screen, but all the checkbuttons seem to be selected. How do I avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All checkbuttons are sharing the same variable $ckval. Maybe you want a radiobutton instead?

Answer (score 0):

@Slaven is right: you are using the same variable. You could use a hash table or an array instead.

```
my $i=1;
my $n=5;
my $incr=1;
my @ckval;
while($i <= $n){
    $mw->Checkbutton(-text=>$i,-variable=>\$ckval[$i],->command=>sub{
             if($ckval[$i]){ print $i; }
    })->pack;
    $i=$i+$incr;
}
```